# in mfc how to implement dockable dialog?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, panel, dockable

i am working on a Dialog based application in MFC, I need something just like visual studio's left panel, right panel, bottom panelwhich have a close button to close the panel.
Anyone know how to implement this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [MFC Feature Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309030.aspx).